# How to never auto-save large files — or, how to run a function whenever any buffer starts — or, how to abort loading a minor mode in one of its hooks

Tags: hooks, minor-mode, auto-save

I want to tell Emacs to never auto-save files bigger than ~1MB. I know how to turn off `auto-save-mode` when the file size is above a certain limit, but not how to make that function run automatically in every buffer. I don't want to add a mode hook for every major mode.

This was my naive attempt to use `auto-save-mode-hook` to solve the problem:

```
(add-hook 'auto-save-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (buffer-file-name)
                (if (> (file-attribute-size
                        (file-attributes
                         (buffer-file-name)))
                       1000000)
                    (auto-save-mode 0))
              (auto-save-mode 0))))
```

I get an error about excessively deep nesting; presumably, running `(auto-save-mode 0)` is executing `auto-save-mode-hook` again. I'm not quite sure why this would happen, given that it is turning off the mode, not turning it on, but clearly this approach is not going to work as I wrote it. Does anyone have either an alternate strategy or a fix to mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> presumably, running (auto-save-mode 0) is executing auto-save-mode-hook again. I'm not quite sure why this would happen, given that it is turning off the mode, not turning it on,

`C-h f auto-save-mode`: "... The mode’s hook is called both when the mode is **enabled** and when it is **disabled**. ..."

So your code will run again and again.

---

You may need to **check whether the mode is on before toggling** it.

Just draft:

```lisp
(add-hook 'auto-save-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (when (and buffer-auto-save-file-name
                         (>= buffer-saved-size 0))
                ;; OK, auto-save-mode is enabled.
                ;; Maybe you want to disable it.
                (when (Do_you_want_to_turn_off_it?)
                  (auto-save-mode -1)))))
```

Comment: Why do we check whether `buffer-saved-size` is greater than or equal to zero? Is it not sufficient to check `buffer-auto-save-file-name`?

Comment: @Zorgoth: `buffer-saved-size` may be negative so that auto-saving won’t happen **temporarily** but actually it is on. The statements about `auto-save-mode` in the help doc are a little vague IMHO because the doc says “To check whether the minor mode is enabled in the current buffer, evaluate ‘`(and buffer-auto-save-file-name (>= buffer-saved-size 0))`’.” But in my trials, `auto-save-mode-hook` is NOT called after evaluating `(setq buffer-saved-size -1)`. Checking only `buffer-auto-save-file-name` will be fine in your case :-)